# Consequences of --allow-unrelated-histories flag

Tags: git, git-merge

Here is the situation:

- I cloned a large ongoing project repository say `RepoA`
- Copied all the files without `.git` folder to new folder `RepoB`
- Did `git init` and added **different remote** in the RepoB
- I worked on the `RepoB` and pushed many commits to the remote
- They also pushed many commits to RepoA

Now, I want to merge my work with their repo. This is what I did in `RepoA`.

```
git checkout develop  
git remote add repoBOrigin https://www.cloud.com/repoB.git   
git fetch repoBOrigin aBranchOfRepoB // all of the work is in this branch  
git merge repoBOrigin/aBranchOfRepoB
```

And I got this error: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

I looked up this on stackoverflow and found out that this can be solved by using `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag but **this comes with a warning that this should be used in rare cases.**

Now, my actual concern is that what consequences/issues this flag will cause. How will the git history of RepoA shape up?

No one explained the aftermath of merging unrelated histories. As the project is quite large in scale, I have to be very careful before pushing anything stupid to their repo.

Answer (score 6):

> my actual concern is that what effects/issues `--allow-unrelated-histories` will cause ...

The *flag itself* doesn't cause anything.  What it does is enable an action that isn't what new Git users expect.

To understand it—or Git in general, really—you need to have some basic knowledge about graphs, as defined by the usual mathematical definition in which a graph *G* is a collection of vertices *V* connected by edges *E*, or written in the usual notation, *G = (V, E)*.  When the edges have a direction—a sort of one-way arrow, so that each vertex (or node) "goes to" another vertex but you can't necessarily go back, the edges are called *arcs*.

In Git, the *commit graph* is directed like this: each commit acts as graph node, and it lists its *parent commit(s)*.  These are the outgoing arcs, so they connect commits in a sort of backwards fashion.  Git's *branch names* then work to find the *last* commit, so that in a tiny, three-commit repository, you would have:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

Commit `A` is the first commit you ever made, so it has no parent.  Commit `B` lists commit `A` as its parent, and `C` lists `B` as its parent; and Git finds commit `C`—whose real name, which is its hash ID, looks quite random—using the name `master` to hold `C`'s hash ID.

Knowing that these links—the arcs—all go backwards, from child to parent, we can draw them more conveniently as links, and add more commits:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- branch
```

If we now go to *merge* the branch back into `master`, Git uses these connecting arrows to figure out where, in history, your work on `master` split apart from someone else's work in `branch`.  That's back at commit `B`, where the graph nodes rejoin.  So Git can now compare the snapshot saved in this merge base `B` to the tip of `master`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-D>
```

to figure out what *you* changed.  Then Git can compare the snapshot in `B` to that in the tip of `branch`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-G>
```

The act of merging—the *to merge* verb—makes these two diffs and combines them, applying the combined changes to whatever was in the base commit.  If all goes well, Git commits the final result on its own.  (If not, Git stops, and makes you clean up the mess and do the commit yourself; what goes into that commit depends on how *you* fix the conflicts that Git found.)  The result is a *merge commit*, with not one but *two* parents:

```
A--B--C--D---H   <-- master (HEAD)
    \       /
     E--F--G   <-- branch
```

Again, the *source code snapshot* for the new merge commit `H` is the result of *combining the changes* made since the merge base—the common starting point of the two branch tips.

In your case, however, you've made two *unrelated repositories*.  The result is what mathematicians call a [disconnected graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisconnectedGraph.html).  It might look something like this, for instance:

```
A--B--C--D---H   <-- br1
    \       /
     E--F--G

        L--M
       /    \
I--J--K------N   <-- br2
```

If you now `git checkout` one of these two branches, so that `HEAD` is attached to, say, `br1`, and run `git merge br2`, Git goes to find the common starting point, working backwards (leftwards) from the two branch tips.  But there is no common start point: the histories are unrelated.

Old versions of Git would just go ahead and merge.  New ones complain unless you supply the flag; if you supply the flag, they go ahead and merge, in exactly the same way.

The issue here is that there *is no common starting point*, so what Git does is assume that the common starting point is a *truly empty commit:* a commit with no files at all in it.

This means that every file in each of the two branches is newly-created.  Two files with the *same* path name will cause an "add/add conflict": Git says that *you* wrote `README.txt` from scratch, and *they* wrote `README.txt` from scratch, and Git itself has no idea how to combine these, so you must do that yourself.  This repeats for every file with the same name.

On the other hand, if you created a `README.md` and they created a `README.rst`, the two names differ, so Git assumes that the correct way to combine `README.md` with nothing is to take `README.md`, and the correct way to combine `README.rst` with nothing is to take `README.rst`.  So you end up with both files, and Git believes they are now combined correctly.  (Is that true?  I have no idea.  Neither does Git, but Git *assumes* it's true.)

This repeats for all files: either each file name is unique to that particular diff, so Git adds it, or it's not, so Git declares a conflict and leaves it up to you to fix the problem.  At the end, if there were no file name conflicts, Git makes the new commit on its own; if there were conflicts, Git makes you clean them up and do the commit yourself.  We can draw the new commit:

```
A--B--C--D---H-----O   <-- br1 (HEAD)
    \       /     /
     E--F--G     /
                /
        L--M   /
       /    \ /
I--J--K------N   <-- br2
```

Was this a sensible thing to do?  I cannot answer that; only you can answer that.